# $(document).on('change','.child-21',function(){ }); with dynamic class

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make my function, whenever I click on radio button I want to call dynamic class like - child-21-1, child-22-2. But I don't know how to make class dynamic in:

```
$(document).on('change','.child-21', function() {});
```

On this basis i want to show hide other `div`'s.

```
$(document).on('change','.child-21',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='No') {
        $('.class-1').show();
        $('.class-2').show();
        $('.class-3').show();
        $('.class-4').show();
    } else if($(this).val()=='Yes') {
        $('.class-1').hide();
        $('.class-2').hide();
        $('.class-3').hide();
        $('.class-4').hide();
    } else {
        if ($('#ssn1').prop("checked") == true){
            $('#single-text').hide();
            $('.class-2').hide();
        } else if($('#ssn1').prop("checked") == false) {
            $('#single-text').show();
            $('.class-2').hide();
        } else {
            $('.child-21-div').slideDown();
            $('.class-2').hide();
        }   
    }
});
```

Html Code

```
<div class="radio-inline">
    <input id="over21" type="radio" name="over21[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class="child-21<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Yes" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['step4a_data']['over21'][$i]) && $_SESSION['step4a_data']['over21'][$i]=='Yes') ?'checked':''; ?>><label for="radio1">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <input id="over22" type="radio" name="over21[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class="child-21<?php echo $i; ?>" value="No" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['step4a_data']['over21'][$i]) && $_SESSION['step4a_data']['over21'][$i]=='No') ?'checked':''; ?> ><label for="radio2"> No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's not working as i want to call class with $(document).on('change','.child-21',function(){ }); this is on change.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The `else` path will never be taken with what code you have given. Also, when matching these strings, use `===` instead of `==`. It's ca cleaner solution and you are making sure you are matching the strings

Comment: try to create a working example of your final code (jsfiddle), without the php stuff so we can better help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show/hide other `div` elements depending upon the checkbox value, see the code below:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() { // This is shorthand in jQuery for once document has loaded
    $('#over21').on('change', function() {
        console.log("The user is over 21.");
        $('#over21-div').show();
        $('#over22-div').hide();
    });
    $('#over22').on('change', function() {
        console.log("The user is over 22.");
        $('#over22-div').show();
        $('#over21-div').hide();
    });        
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="radio-inline">
    <input id="over21" type="radio" name="over21" class="child-21" value="Yes" unchecked><label for="radio1">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <input id="over22" type="radio" name="over21" class="child-21" value="No" unchecked><label for="radio2"> No</label>
</div>
<div id="over21-div">
    <p>Only shows if yes.</p>
</div>
<div id="over22-div">
    <p>Only shows if no.</p>
</div>
```

See the working code as a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2nbgsbxs/).

P.S. Note that I've removed the inline PHP. which I'd advise against so heavily - separate your PHP into functions, then call them inline so you have as little PHP in your HTML as possible. For instance, compare:

```
<p><?php if (someBoolean) { echo "Bad result."; } elseif (someOtherBoolean && checkbox.booleanReturningFunction()) { echo "Some worse result"; } elseif (life.hasMeaning()) { echo "This is getting confusing."; } else { echo "Yay it worked."; } ?></p>
```

to:

```
<!-- Nearer the top of our HTML document -->
<?php
    function awesome_function() {
        if (someBoolean) { 
            echo "Bad result."; 
        } elseif (someOtherBoolean && checkbox.isUserCoolEnough()) { 
            echo "Some worse result"; 
        } elseif (life.hasMeaning()) { 
            echo "This is getting confusing."; 
        } else { 
            echo "Yay it worked."; 
    } 
?>

...

<!-- At the inline area -->
<p><?php awesome_function(); ?></p>
```

which is much nicer, and more maintainable

Answer (score 0):

Bind change method after updating your html

```
$('.child-21').unbind();
if($('.child-21').length > 0 && $._data($('.child-21')[0],"events") == undefined){
    $('.child-21').bind('change',function(){
        // write your code
    });
}
```